# Jmeter: how do I click confirmation email link?

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

my performance test includes

1. A regex to extract confirmation email from gmail client, and then
2. I have an http request that renders the confirmation url
   So mail Reader Sampler
   includes REgex extractor as child
   Then http request page to use the variable from regex extractor.
   But somehow I get 404 error.

I have attached my regex code.
The comments section shows various regex's that I have tried

This is my regex

```
<RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">link</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">https://([^/].*)&amp;form_action=validate</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">0</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="RegexExtractor.default_empty_value">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">encryption2.emktg2.info(.*?)&quot;  and encryption2.emktg2.info/campaign-jmeter/thanks.page(.*?) and href=\&quot;(.*?)\&quot; and https://([^/]*)/</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="Sample.scope">all</stringProp>
</RegexExtractor>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** we can't click using Jmeter, instead we capture and send the url (i.e., to be clicked/submitted) using http sampler. i.e., simulate the HTTP request, that is triggered when you click Confirmation email link.

**Long answer:**

1. Capture the url (confirmation link) that you received in confirmation mail (using regular expression extractor)
2. Add one more http sampler (let's call it as confirm HTTP Sampler), after "mail reader" sampler, in which you extract the url to be cliked/submitted. In the server name, port, protocol, path and body fields (No need that all parameters to be present in confirmation link), provide the values that are captured using regular expression extractor. I would suggest to capture all parameters separately using multipls groups, specified using parenthesis "()", and templates, $1$, $2$ etc. (number of groups match to number of templates)
3. Add all required headers using Header Manager as child to "confirm Sampler". 
   **Note:** To know, which all headers to add (like **Cookie**, **Reference** etc), capture the request from browser using network sniffers like wireshark, burpsuite etc, or use in-built browser options like F12, under Network tab.

**Suggestion:** please add Debug sampler (to see the captured url using regular expression extractor) at the end of all samplers, and View results Tree (to see the actual request sent and the response received.).